# Prove the following inequality if a and are reals

Tags: inequality

Prove inequality $(a^3+b^3) ≤ (a^2 + b^2)(a^4 + b ^4)$  where $a,b$ are reals

They are given reals so cannot apply AM-GM inequality or can we?

Also I am a beginner in inequality so please try to keep it simple....
Thanks in advance

I tried it in the following way:

$a^2 + b^2 ≥ 2ab$

$a^4 + b^4 ≥ 2a^2b^2$

So.. $$(a^2 + b^2)(a^4 + b^4) ≥ 4a^3b^3$$

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Please use mathjax just enclose it with $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that by Cauchy-Schwarz
\begin{align}
a^3+b^3 = a\cdot a^2+b\cdot b^2 \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{(a^2)^2+(b^2)^2}.
\end{align}

By homogeneity, the inequality as written in the problem is not right. For instance, let $a = b = 1/2$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\nleq \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4} \right)\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{8}= \frac{1}{16}
\end{align}

Comment: I am a beginner and I am not familiar with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is there any other way?

Comment: If you have taken Cal 3 then you will know. Because it is just $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = \|\vec{a}\| \|\vec{b}\|\cos \theta \le \|\vec{a}\| \|\vec{b}\|\$.

Comment: @Ralf Just use the identity $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)={ac+bd)}^2+{(ad-bc)}^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is false: $a=\frac1 2 , b=0$ isa  counter-example.

However, it becomes correct if you square the left side. To prove this apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality after splitting $a^{3}$ as $(a) (a^{2}) $ and $b^{3}$ as $(b) (b^{2}) $.